# Adding query string date parameters to linked URL

Tags: forms, hyperlink, send, url-parameters, query-string

I'm working for a tennisclubb and need to create a button on our page that sends the user to our booking system. The thing is that the URL ends with query string parameters, http://../../boka_reserve_reg_client_app.php?sess_adm_club_id=25&YEAR=2016&MONTH=04&DAY=26.

If I crop the URL right before the first "&" you will still be able to access the booking page but it will not have any function.

So what I need is a form that submits the parameters to the end of the URL where the user types the year, month and day or a pice of code that generates a new link every day with the correct date.

Is this possible to fix without using PHP? JavaScript is absolutely fine.

Thanks!